# Lock screen doesn't cause onStop() to get called

Tags: android

My app uses GPS, so I remove GPS updates in onStop() so it doesn't use up battery when it shouldn't.  However, I noticed that the battery on my test phone was running down if my app was open when the lock screen comes on.

So to test it, I added a Log.i(...) to the onStop() method of my activity. Sure enough, onStop() does not get called when I press the off button on my HTC Incredible (which turns off the screen).

Is there any way to listen for the lock screen, or the screen turning off, since it doesn't call onStop() like it should?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

onStop is not guaranteed to be called, onPause is. Use onPause to remove GPS updates from eating battery.